# How to load vector layer slices in Leaflet by bounding boxes while caching locally?

Tags: leaflet

[Loading geojson via ajax in leaflet using bbox](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213204/loading-geojson-via-ajax-in-leaflet-using-bbox) and [How to add a bounding box filter to this leaflet WFS request?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169129/how-to-add-a-bounding-box-filter-to-this-leaflet-wfs-request?noredirect=1&lq=1) both answer how to request vector layer data within a leaflet map by the map's bounding box. However both answers discard the vector layer's data when refreshing, with no caching of the results. I foresee some kind of merging `olddata` and `newdata` arrays while removing duplicates and then redrawing the layer.

I found the [`leaflet-tilelayer-geojson` plugin](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/) which creates a leaflet geojson layer from tiles of json, served from a request of URL `http://{s}.somedomain.com/blabla/{z}/{x}/{y}.json`, but the plugin [has not been updated](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/issues/27) for leaflet 1.0

Is there a commonly accepted method/plugin for caching this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [leaflet plugins page](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#vector-tiles) there seem to be 2 current plugins for [vector tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec) based on the Mapbox spec.

- [geojson-vt](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt) which slices the GeoJSON client-side
- [leaflet.VectorGrid](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.VectorGrid) which can take an external hosted protobuf source like `https://free-{s}.tilehosting.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`, otherwise it will use `geojson-vt` as per above

Mapzen's [Tangram](https://mapzen.com/products/tangram/) is a [Leaflet Plugin](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram#quickstart) which also [supports GeoJSON vector tile sources](https://mapzen.com/documentation/tangram/sources/#). Though the focus seems on style, you can [add custom events](https://mapzen.com/documentation/tangram/Javascript-API/#hover-and-click) to feature `hover` or `click`